# java - TimerTask - why my code behaves like that?

Tags: java, timertask, timer-jobs

I wrote the following code:

```
private void Button_StartMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
            java.util.Timer().schedule( 
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() { 
                        Find(word_from_textfield); 
                }
            }, 
            10
    );
    }

public void Find (String word) {

    String[] array_files = new String[100];

int j;        
for (j=0; j<array_files.length; j++) {
if (array_files[j] != null) {   

        if (array_files[j].contains("1")) {
            function1 (  array_files[j], word ); // function1() prints some line on a textpane
         } 

        else if (     array_files[j].contains("2")   ) 
        {
        function2 (  array_files[j], word); // function2() prints some line on a textpane
        } 

        else if (     array_files[j].contains("3")    ) 
       {
        function3 (   array_CARTELLE[j], word  ); // function3() prints some line on a textpane
        } 

       }            
}        
}
```

I have put the Find() function inside a `TimerTask()`.
As you can see the function calls other functions that appends some lines on a textpane some checks.

The result is that my program prints those lines one by one, each line is printed after the previous after few milliseconds, that's because I used `Timer().schedule()`.

I tried to call the Find() method without using the `Timer`. The result was that my program ran and when it called my Find() method it stuck for a moment and after that it printed all the lines at the same time.

I'd like to understand why it happened. I mean, when I chose to use`Timer().schedule()` I expected that my Find() method would have ran after 10 milliseconds but after that time it would have printed all my lines at same time without freezing my program, but I did not expect to see the lines printed one by one in different moments.

So I'd like to know:

- why I had a behaviour like that using `Timer().schedule()`.
- and why my program has stuck for a moment while running my Find()
  method.

Comment: your programm was stuck when calling your find() method, because it was a synchronous call, who stopped your thread until the method returned. By using a timer, your method is executed in another thread, an by that your "main" program code doesn't stop.

Comment: ok thanks, so it means that, if I call another method (for example try()) after find() method and it needs to use the printed lines by find() method, what would happen then?
Thanks